# Can I access the views in django from an android application through urls we define on the urlconfig or should I need an API?

Tags: android, python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner in django. I covered the basic poll application in the django site. Now I want my android app to communicate with django application. As I googled, the suggestion was to build an API. But is it possible to access the server from an android application like I access the views from my browser using urls, as suggested in the basic poll app in the django site. Or should I use an API?

Answer (score 1):

You should use api for that however you can use webview in android dev.